# the use of threads and the java Future interface in AWS Lambda

Tags: java, multithreading, google-cloud-firestore, aws-lambda

I want to create an AWS Lambda function in java that writes to a database in Firestore. The short story is that, while the code does what it should when I execute it
on my own computer, using NetBeans (the truth is that it works most of the time, but not always, maybe due to problems with my internet connection), nothing at all
happens when I deploy it as a Lambda function and invoke this. I suspect that this has less to do with Firestore itself, but rather with how AWS Lambda handles asynchronous
operations.

Now to the details!

As a simple example, the method that writes to the Firestore object db reads

```
public static void writeFirestore(Firestore db){
        try{
            DateTime now = DateTime.now();
            String time = now.toString();
            Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
            data.put("time", time);
            String collTitle = "Notebook";
            String docTitle = "Document: "+time;
            db.collection(collTitle).document(docTitle).set(data);
            System.out.println("wrote to Firestore");
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Could not write to db: "+e.toString());
        }
}
```

Now, as it takes some time to connect to Firestore and initialize db, I want to make sure that db is not passed as an argument into writeFirestore() before it
has been properly retrieved. So, I define a version of db in the form of a Future object, using ExecutorService, and then retrieve
the object db with the get()-method. For this, I define the class TaskRunner:

```
    public class TaskRunner {
    
        ExecutorService executor;
    
        public TaskRunner(){
            executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        }
    
        public static interface Callback<T>{
        
            public void onCallback(T result);
        }
                      
    
    
        public <T> void executeAsync(Callable<T> callable, Callback<T> callback) throws Exception{
        
            try{
                Future future = executor.submit(callable);
                Object result = future.get();
                if(result != null){
                    System.out.println("result is not null; applying callback...");
                    callback.onCallback((T) result);
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("result is null");
                }
            
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("Problem running executeAsync: "+e.toString());
            }
        
        
       
        }
    
    }
```

Writing the example document to my fixed database db now goes as follows:

1. I define the class FirestoreCreator that implements Callable with the purpose of retrieving the Firestore object db:

```
    public static class FirestoreCreator implements Callable<Firestore>{

            @Override
            public Firestore call() throws Exception {
            
            
            
                String projectId = "myProjectId";

        
                GoogleCredentials credentials = 
                    GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream("myCredentialsFile.json"));
            

                FirestoreOptions firestoreOptions = FirestoreOptions.getDefaultInstance()
                    .toBuilder()
                    .setProjectId(projectId)
                    .setCredentials(credentials)
                    .build();
                Firestore db = firestoreOptions.getService();
                return db;
            }
        
    }
```

2. I implement the TaskRunner.Callback interface using writeFirestore().
3. I create a TaskRunner object, taskRunner, and call its executeAsync() method with the above two objects as parameters.

These three steps are collected in the final method testUpdateFirestore() that does the job:

```
    public static void testUpdateFirestoreInterface(){
         
            FirestoreCreator fsCreator = new FirestoreCreator();
        
            TaskRunner.Callback<Firestore> updateCallback = new TaskRunner.Callback<Firestore>() {
                @Override
                public void onCallback(Firestore result) {
                    writeFirestore(result);
                }
            };
        
            TaskRunner taskRunner = new TaskRunner();
            try {
                taskRunner.executeAsync(fsCreator, updateCallback);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("Failed to run executeAsync");
           
            }
        
        
    }
```

As I already mentioned in the introduction, the code works (most times) when I run it on my computer, but not at all in AWS Lambda. No exception is thrown, and yet no document has been written in Firestore.

The discussion about threads in AWS Lambda (https://dzone.com/articles/multi-threaded-programming-with-aws-lambda) made me suspect that reason is that the use of some thread that runs when ExecutorService is used is not being handled properly.

Does anyone know what goes wrong and what a solution could look like?

Comment: What is the benefit of threads here?  You appear to be only spawning a single thread.  I tend to think that a Lambda is conceptually similar to a thread - a single execution that takes care of something.  If I need more parallelism I spawn more Lambdas, not threads.

Comment: How would you use another Lambda in this example?